# Winrate of opponent vs another apponent

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to find the most efficient way to build a counter warehouse.

shortened the tables just to needed info for question

Match Table

```
MatchId, version, type
```

MatchParticipants

```
matchId, playerid, characterid, teamid (only team1 or team2), winner (1 or 0)

10 of these rows per match
```

Characters

```
characterid, name
```

So i have thought of doing a cross join of characters on characters and that gives me all the possibilities of opponents for said character then i would have do a massive subquery to look into the matches table where the id's were on opposite teams.

Any ideas essentially what i see the warehouse table looking like.

```
character1.characterid, character1.name,
character2.characterid, character2.name, 
winrate of character1 over character2
```

Comment: what's the relationship between players and characters?  Is characterID the player's opponent playerID?

Comment: no the player plays a character i should have left the playerid out it doesnt have any revelance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that this query should meet your expectations:

```
SELECT x.[first] AS CharacterId,
       c.name,
       x.[second] AS CharacterId,
       c1.name,
       wins/loses AS ratio
FROM         
(
SELECT  m.CharacterId [first],
        m1.CharacterId [second],
        SUM(m.winner) AS wins,
        SUM(m1.winner) AS loses
FROM    MatchParticipants m
        INNER JOIN MatchParticipants m1 ON m.MatchId = m1.MatchId AND m.TeamId <> m1.TeamId
        GROUP BY
        m.CharacterId,
        m1.CharacterId
) x
LEFT JOIN Characters c ON x.[first] = c.characterid
LEFT JOIN Characters c1 ON x.[second] = c1.characterid
```

Answer (score 0):

is this what you're looking for?

```
SELECT
  *,
  100.0 * matches/wins AS winRate
FROM
  (SELECT
    teamid,
    playerid,
    characterid AS opponentID,
    COUNT(matchId) AS matches,
    SUM(winner) AS wins
  FROM
    MatchParticipants
  GROUP BY
    teamid,
    playerid,
    characterid) w
```